# Unresolved reference: addCriteria (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to write some basic MongoDB custom queries in Kotlin.

I've seen nearly everywhere that people use a method `addCriteria`:

```
val query: Query = Query()
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("field1").exists(true)))
```

But it seems there is no method addCriteria in Query which I use: `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query`

I am very confused. Cannot find any explanations on how to write custom MongoDB queries in Kotlin with Spring Data except using this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was very close to the problem's solution. I really used wrong Query, despite it's path looks really logical. I needed this one: `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query`.
I used `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query`, which is Query annotation, not the class